# windows autologon in background

Tags: windows-7, login, domain, user

I have a domain connected Windows 7. On this pc two domain users can connect. One is my personal user that I currently use, the other is a user that I need in order to remotely launch tasks on this pc from other pcs. So I'd like to login this last user silently and eventually disconnect it (not logoff, I need an active session) wthout affecting the normal use of my user. How can I do it?
Thank you